# Forecast package not installing R Studio Mac

Tags: r, macos, installation, forecasting

I'm trying to download the 'forecast' package in my R-Studio and I keep getting the following error. Can someone please explains to me what all this means?

The first warning I get is :-

updateTBATSMatrices.cpp:38:10: warning: unused variable 'gammaVector' [-Wunused-variable]
        double *gammaVector;
                ^
1 warning generated.

The second warning I get is :-

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [forecast.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'forecast'

Comment: you say "download" are you using the command "install.packages"?

Comment: Yes :) I'm doing it through the install screen in r studio.

Comment: This is something I skipped in the initial question. This is the end of the warning message: * removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/forecast'

Comment: What version of R studio, OSX and R do you have?

Comment: My R Studio is Version 1.0.153. My OSX is Version 10.10.5. My R is version 3.2.3

Comment: So if you try this install.packages("forecast") it also fails?  Did you try to install it outside of R studio?

Comment: Just tried install.packages("forecast") and it still gives me the exact same errors. I've never tried to install something outside R studio and am not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Matter resolved! Thanks guys!

Comment: The solution was that my R and R-Studio were not up to date.